# Searching a document for specific strings, then print out a part of that string

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

So in my program im attempting to search a document called console.log that has lines like this:

```
65536:KONSOLL:1622118174:NSN:ActivationUnits::HandleActivationUnitsMessages. There is no handler for FNo: 34
65536:KONSOLL:1622177574:NSN:ActivationUnits::HandleActivationUnitsMessages. There is no handler for FNo: 34
65536:KONSOLL:1622190642:NSN:From AutroSafe: 28 5 2021, 08:30:42; 05.046; Service: "Self Verify" mislykket; ;  ; ProcessMsg; F:2177 L:655; 53298;1;13056;; 
65536:KONSOLL:1622204573:NSN:ActivationUnits::HandleActivationUnitsMessages. There is no handler for FNo: 34
```

In my input i always specify "Self Verify" as im looking after that. I want the detectornumber (05.046) on the output. But i get a error.

This is my code:

```
import os
import re

pattern = input("What are you searching for? -->")
detectorPattern = re.compile(r'\d\d.\d\d\d')
directory = os.listdir()
for x in range(len(directory)):
    with open(directory[x], 'r') as reader:
        print("Opening " + directory[1])
        # Read and print the entire file line by line
        for line in reader:
            findLine = re.search(pattern, line)
            if findLine is not None:
                mo = detectorPattern.search(findLine)
                print(mo.group())
```

So what im trying to do is to to go for one line, and if i find "Self Verify" i will search that line for the detector specified in detectorPattern, and print that one out.

This is the error i get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\haral\Desktop\PP\SVFinder.py", line 14, in <module>
    mo = detectorPattern.search(findLine)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Comment: So what is your question here?

Comment: It doesnt work. I get a error, going to update my post

Comment: try changing ```mo = detectorPattern.search(findLine)``` to ```mo = detectorPattern.search(findLine.string)``` and see if that is what you are looking for.  The object findLine is an re.match object and you probably want the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
mo = detectorPattern.search(findLine)
```

To:

```
mo = detectorPattern.search(findLine.string)
```

This will print:

```
162219
```

when executing the line:

```
print(mo.group())
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you put directly `line` into `detectorPattern.search`.
Also please not `if x is not None:` can be replaced by `if x:`

This example should works as is:

```
import re

pattern = "Self Verify"
reader = ['65536:KONSOLL:1622118174:NSN:ActivationUnits::HandleActivationUnitsMessages. There is no handler for FNo: 34',
          '65536:KONSOLL:1622177574:NSN:ActivationUnits::HandleActivationUnitsMessages. There is no handler for FNo: 34',
          '65536:KONSOLL:1622190642:NSN:From AutroSafe: 28 5 2021, 08:30:42; 05.046; Service: "Self Verify" mislykket; ;  ; ProcessMsg; F:2177 L:655; 53298;1;13056;; ',
          '65536:KONSOLL:1622204573:NSN:ActivationUnits::HandleActivationUnitsMessages. There is no handler for FNo: 34]']

for line in reader:
    findLine = re.search(pattern, line)
    detectorPattern = re.compile(r'\d\d.\d\d\d')
    if findLine:
        detector = detectorPattern.search(line).group()
        print(detector)
```

Output:

```
162219
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want the detectornumber (05.046) on the output

This seems to do the job. I just changed findLine by pattern in detectorPattern.

```
import os
import re

pattern = input("What are you searching for? -->")
detectorPattern = re.compile(r'\d\d.\d\d\d')
directory = os.listdir()
for x in range(len(directory)):
    with open(directory[x], 'r') as reader:
        print("Opening " + directory[1])
        # Read and print the entire file line by line
        for line in reader:
            findLine = re.search(pattern, line)
            if findLine is not None:
                mo = detectorPattern.search(pattern)
                print(mo.group())
```